# WP7 - How can I retrieve the mini form of a Path at runtime?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, geometry

I've got a databound series of predefined shapes (Path with Data="" set) which each trigger the same event when clicked.
I'd like to programmatically access the mini form of the Path.Data property at runtime to be able to persist it.

In this case I *could* just name the elements and on click check which one, however I'd prefer a more generic solution.
There seem to be some WPF workarounds but I haven't seen any for WP7.

Does anyone know if this is possible? and if so, how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting that if the path is loaded with figures up front (or Xaml Loaded from path data) instead of via setting the Path data directly a technique like this http://stringtopathgeometry.codeplex.com/ should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in to if and how this may be possible I came across http://www.eightyeightpercentnerd.dreamhosters.com/?p=40 and even though it's quite old it explains how a paths data/geometry is parsed in Siverlight.
It leads me to think that you may be better off trying to find a different approach to solving your problem. :(

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm currently databinding the Path data to viewmodel with the data string itself so that I can retrieve it as the datacontext. It works, but I'd hoped for a way to get this data back out without resorting to this.

Comment: I *think* the issue is that you can't as the mini-language is one way as not everything can be represented in it.

Comment: That's what my research was pointing at too. The question is part hopeful punt into a future answer.